# gulp browser sync open chrome only

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, windows-7, gulp

I am attempting to open Chrome and Firefox when browser-sync module initializes the web server.

My gulp task has the following:

```
browserSync.init(null, {
  files: config.destination.root + '/**/*',
  browser: ["google chrome", "firefox"],
  port: config.port,
  notify: false,
  server: {
    baseDir: config.destination.root
  },
  startPath: config.pocSuffix
}, callback);
```

My current default is set to IE.

It is still opening only IE.  How do i troubleshoot this?

Comment: I am still not quite sure why the IE was being fired, but i was able to fix the issue by providing browser: "chrome" option.

Comment: I'm having the same issue but I'm trying to open it in Safari, passing "safari" as an option doesn't work though...

Comment: @ithil were you able to fix it eventually, want me to test it on my end?  What version of browser-sync are you using?

Answer (score 5):

To me it seems that neither "google chrome" nor "firefox" was found in your instance, and that IE then kicked in as the default one.

In my scenario I have a Ubuntu 15.10 minimal install with openbox, and chrome set as default browser. Various configurations and results follows:

1. No browsersync browser set. spawns firefox
2. "google chrome" set. error: spawn google chrome ENOENT.
3. "chrome" set. error: spawn google chrome ENOENT.
4. "google-chrome" set in browsersync. spawns chrome

Using "chrome" solved it for you. Using "google-chrome" solved it for me.

Mentioning it as an answer, in case someone ends up here by googling the issue.

Comment: platform specific for sure.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: bless you (and your hyphen!)

Comment: On my Ubuntu 16.10 running Chromium, I had to use `browser: "chromium-browser"`. I guess the rule is that the name needs to match whatever is in the process table.